# boost::python - how to invoke a python function in its own thread from C++?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-python

I have a module written in python. this module is sort of an interface to many different functionalities I implemented in Python:

EmbeddingInterface.py simply imports this module and creates an instance:

```
import CPPController

cppControllerInstance = CPPController()
```

I would like to use cppControllerInstance in c++. this is what I have done so far:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <boost\python.hpp>

using namespace boost;

python::object createController()
{
    try
    {
        Py_Initialize();

        python::object mainModule = python::import("__main__");
        python::object mainNamespace = mainModule.attr("__dict__");

        python::dict locals;

        python::exec(
            "print \"loading python implementetion:\"\n"
            "import sys\n"
            "sys.path.insert(0, \"C:\\Projects\\Python\\ProjectName\\Panda\")\n"
            "import EmbeddingInterface\n"
            "controller = EmbeddingInterface.cppControllerInstance\n",
            mainNamespace, locals);

            python::object controller = locals["controller"];
            return controller;
    }
    catch(...) {}
}
```

**The Problem:**

This 'controller' has some functions which must be called asynchronously.
its work is continuous and in addition it can throw exceptions.
which is why std::async sounded great.

But it doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
    python::object controller = createController();
    python::object loadScene = controller.attr("loadScene");
    //loadScene(); // works OK but blocking!
    std::async(loadScene); // non blocking but nothing happens!
    while(true); // do some stuff
}
```

I tried to invoke the python function 'loadScene' with its own thread but the function seemed to be blocking. It never returns.

What is the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you misunderstood  the behavior of  [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

a snippet of test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int doSomething(){
  std::cout << "do something"<<std::endl;
  return 1;
}

int main(){
   auto f = std::async(doSomething);

   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
   std::cout <<"wait a while"<<std::endl;
   f.get();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
wait a while
do something
```

change the line

```
auto f = std::async(doSomething);
```

to

```
auto f = std::async(std::launch::async,doSomething);
```

Then output:

```
do something
wait a while
```

As your example, to run it immediately in another thread, you can try :

```
std::async(std::launch::async,loadScene);
```

Comment: Indeed, at the time I did not understand the behavior of std::async and the fact the std::future destructor blocks. But regarding calling a python function on a different c++ thread, it is not as simple as you illustrate and requires manipulating with the GIL (python global interpreter lock).